# Convert .SGI file to Excel file format in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, converters

I need to convert a .sgi file to Excel file in a ASP.Net page. Is there any converters available for that.

Comment: What is an `.sgi` file?

Comment: Also, you generally never convert to an actual Excel (`.xls` or `.xlsx`) file because it's a proprietary binary format (or in the case of `.xlsx`, a horribly complicated zipped XML format). If it's tabular data you usually just convert it to a CSV file. If you want to create an actual spreadsheet file (with formulas, charts and other objects) then you'd use a library like Aspose.

Comment: Please see this [link](http://www.fileformat.info/format/sgiimage/egff.htm)

Comment: I guess we can't do this. Requirement changed and dropped this work